# Usage of Logitech mouse (M500) button number in Configure Advanced Click

Tags: logitech-mouse

Does anyone know how to program a button with  Configure Advanced Click utilizing a Button number?

The image shown is the Logic control center accessible from Mac System preferences.

[image: ![enter image description here]

Any example would be appreciated.

Comment: What software is that? It's not Logitech Options, nor SteerMouse.

Comment: I SPECULATE the 'Button number' drop down is asking which numpad number key COULD trigger this mouse click (button below scroll wheel it appears) & it's corresponding function you set under 'Click Type'. I think this is a disability/accessibility feature:
https://www.disability.illinois.edu/academic-support/assistive-technology/mac-os-x-mouse-keys

Comment: @gregg - SteerMouse uses Button numbering like this - I just don't recognise that specific page (I had to switch to Logitech Options because of the appalling proprietary behaviour of their MX2 so I've not used it for a while). the first page of SteerMouse has an area you can click to show the button number (which you then sometimes have to remember later).

Comment: I updated my post. Thank you guys! The button number runs from 1 to 8.

Comment: Cool, thanks. I'm afraid I can't help as my MX2 uses the other CP, Logi Options. Wish you luck:)